# Adding a label to Google.maps.advancedMarkerElement?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to port over a map for an application from the depreciated google.maps.Marker to google.maps.advancedMarkerElement, the issue is have is that the application used implement a very old version of Gary Little's Marker with Label.
(Our Version is slighlty newer than this - https://gist.github.com/varatep/ba62923d248eed51b64a). Is there a utility or Library that has similar functionality or do I need to write my own?

I have tried changing the inhertance to be the google.maps.advancedMarkerElement but it is not is not recognising the class and I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.